# Get rendered HTML page file from URL input with browser

Tags: javascript, python, api

What would be fastest and most less consuming (CPU, RAM) way to get JavaScript rendered HTML page and save it on drive based on URL with ordinary browser in headless (Google Chrome or Firefox) mode?
Idea is to also have proxy options in browser changed per request as well.

I'm well aware of Selenium, Puppeteer, PhantomJS and similar solutions. This needs to be done with REAL browser, remotely managed through some API on Linux environment.

I've found only JS API implementations for building addons but haven't found any solutions except [Remote browser](https://github.com/intoli/remote-browser)  for which I'm not sure weather is updated any more.

Any pointers, snippets or whatever are more than welcome since I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for the JavaScript rendered HTML
Page to be functional after it is saved?

Just take a screenshot using Python and save it on drive.

Comment: No, I don't need JS code, I just need HTML that is rendered with JS. If by screenshot you mean .html file that's fine. But I don't need image file.